How to choose normalized filter order from Omega in these attenuation graphs from 1967?
I am trying to understand filter design when it comes to choosing the order from the attenuation graphs for Bessel, Chebyshev or Butterworth filters based on requirements.
My professor instructed to choose the order of the filter from the curves in these graphs closest to the intersection between an Omega value and a stop/passband attenuation value in dB, however, we are not given the definition or formula for that Omega value.
From my understanding in class, it may be related to a value regarding filter normalization referred to as “falloff” or “depth” factor (rough translation from Spanish), written as As=fc/fs for high pass, and As=fs/fc for low pass filters, where fc is the cutoff frequency in Hz and fs is the stopband frequency in Hz.
We are also only given these graphs from “The Handbook of Filter Synthesis” from 1967, which will be the only ones available to us during an upcoming exam on the subject.
I could not find any references online making an association between Omega and As, or even a definition for As in English, so I'd be glad to know, if anyone knows where this Omega value should come from or how it should be calculated, considering the kind of problem, where we will have to employ these graphs will only state the cutoff and stopband frequencies and the gain of the band pass/band suppressor filter as a whole. 

that graph is only for  Butterworth response, other responses have different graphs.

\$\Omega\$ is the "normalized frequency". It's the frequency as a multiple of the cut-off frequency of the filter. Mathematically
$$\Omega=\frac{\omega}{\omega_c}$$
So if you are designing a low-pass filter with 100 Hz cut-off frequency
$$\Omega = \frac{\omega}{2\pi100}$$
If you are designing a notch filter with a 1 GHz critical frequency
$$\Omega = \frac{\omega}{2\pi(1\times10^9)}$$
The point of using a normalized frequency is that it allows these charts to apply to a filter with any cut-off frequency you like, not just one particular design with a specific cut-off frequency.

it may be related to a value regarding filter normalization referred to as "fall off" or "depth" factor ... written as As=fc/fs for high pass and As=fs/fc for low pass filters,

No, it's different.
The chart you have is just giving the response function (often \$|H(\Omega)|\$, with frequency being the frequency of a signal given as input to the filter.
If you want to find the order to achieve a given fall-off factor (as you defined it), you look at the left side of the chart, at an \$\Omega\$ value equal to your \$A_s\$ (i.e. the frequency that is \$A_s\$ times the cut-off frequency) and find what value of \$n\$ is required to achieve the specified minimum attenuation in the stop-band (which should have been given as part of the exercise you are solving).
